# How to use browserlist query in babel preset env targets, with a 'not' keyword properly?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to target last 4 versions of all browsers, except for internet explorer. Here is a part of the webpack config:

```
...
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules/],
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          sourceType: "unambiguous",
          plugins: [
            [
              '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
              {
                // "useESModules": true
              },
            ],
          ],
          presets: [
            [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              {
                'useBuiltIns': 'usage',
                'debug': true,
                'corejs': { version: 3, proposals: true },
                'targets': [ 'last 4 versions and not ie >= 6' ]
              },
            ],
          ],
        },
      }
    ]
  },
...
```

The `'debug': true` option causes targeted browsers to be shown in console log. Why does it target ie 8 and how to prevent that? I don't want the ie to be considered at all.

[image: targets in console log]

Comment: What is the point of this `"and not ie> = 6"` notation?
What do you want to support IE browsers older than IE6 :)
Go here, you have all the documentation [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist)

Comment: I have tried everything, all possible combinations. Interestengly, adding 'and not ie 8' has no effect too. It seems to be a bug. I have solved this problem by using a different query '>0.35%' for now.

Comment: If you want to turn off the IE browser just `not IE > 0` strange solution but it works. And the correct spelling is `'targets': ['last 4 versions', 'not IE > 0']`
This is a array, so this is how it must be entered. If I remember correctly, the size of the letters also matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it better properly
To `package.json` add this:

```
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
},
```

In the webpack, this entry is enough.

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
   loader: 'babel-loader',
  },
}
```

later create the file in root `babel.config.js` and add to it:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        // "debug": true,
        useBuiltIns: 'entry',
        corejs: 3,
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
      {
        regenerator: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

For me, it is much more readable than in the webpack file.
Of course, the necessary libraries are still needed:
`@babel/core`, `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`, `@babel/preset-env`

And one more important thing. In wepback, you must specify a **target: 'browserslist'**, otherwise your configuration from `package.json` will not be taken into account.